# clean up test scripts after tests completed for a class in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I would like to execute some test insert scripts before my test class. Once all the tests in that class are executed, I would like to delete them.For example,

```
@SpringBootTest
@Sql("/test-insert.sql")
public class EmployeeControllerTest{
 //tests here
}
```

I can see some options

1. executing the delete statement in last test by specifying the `@TestOrder` for each of the tests.
2. specifying `@Sql` with executionPhase(before and after for insert and delete) for each of the test methods separately. But, insert/delete will be repeated for every method.
3. using `@AfterAll` to establish a database connection and delete the test inserts.

Is there any cleaner way such as specifying something to clean up at the class level once all the tests in that class are executed?

Comment: are you using a real database instance?
look at testconainers https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test
it can solve your problems with cleaning db after tests

Comment: thanks. Yes, I'm using a real database instance.